# Make a copy of array State in react hook

Tags: reactjs, state, deep-copy

Hello guy I am woking with update function like below:

```
const [listLockerUserType, setListLockerUserTypes] = useState([])

const getData = (content) => {
        let contentLocker = {...content}
        let keys = Object.keys(contentLocker)
        const listLocker = [...listLockerUserType]
         let index = listLocker.findIndex(item => item.userTypeId == content.id)
         listLocker[index][`${keys[1}`] = content[`${keys[1]}`]
         setListLockerUserTypes(listLocker)
        console.log(content)
      }
```

But when I do that it's give me an error

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'description' of object '#<Object>'
```

description is a property of a object of listLockerUserType. Please give me a hint! Thanks you so much!!

Comment: can I ask you why you copy the listLockerUserType into listLocker?

Comment: @novonimo actually listLockerUserType is fetched from my api and i want to update data in listLockerUserType and when user click submit I will call api update

Comment: but you can do this without a copy, using higher-order functions like map() and filter(). have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution just change

```
const listLocker = [...listLockerUserType]
```

to

```
let listLocker = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listLockerUserType))
```